# Intellisense for CLR projects - No Intellisense for e.g. System.Windows.Forms

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've been following two tutorials on some [Visual C++ fundamentals](http://www.functionx.com/vccli/general/introprogramming.htm) but they all seem to lack the information on how I get the intellisense going in Visual Studio 2010.

The following code snippet is what I have

```
#using<mscorlib.dll>
#using<System.Windows.Forms.dll>

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

int main()
{
    MessageBox::Show("ohai!");

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to just write `MessageBox::` and the press ctrl + space and get a nice view of the Methods and properties. But it seems like I don't get that.

Suggestions? Did I miss to include something?

Do I only get intellisense when my IDE knows the Header files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2010 does not currently support IntelliSense in C++/CLI as reported on the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2010/03/09/intellisense-browsing-options-in-vc-2010.aspx).

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) is a commercial VS2010 extension that you may find useful in this regard.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681999/no-intellisense-for-c-cli-in-visual-studio-2010).