# Why is there no intellisense in a CLR/CLI project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clr, c++-cli, intellisense

I don't know if I have done anything wrong, but when I try to write code there are no intellisense popups indicating options or errors. 
I am creating a CLR/CLI type of project with Microsoft's Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681999/no-intellisense-for-c-cli-in-visual-studio-2010 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864022/intellisense-for-clr-projects-no-intellisense-for-e-g-system-windows-forms

Comment: Oh, It says IntelliSence: 'Unavailable for CLR/CLI'.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, Intellisense is not supported in Managed C++ (C++/CLI).

There is a long blog post explaining the details at the [Visual C++ blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx).

Edit: Correcting name of the blog as per comment. :)

Comment: Minor nit - that's the Visual C++ Team Blog, not the [Visual Studio blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/), which is actually just the visual studio platform blog anyways :)

Answer (score 4):

See the 2nd comment, in this blog post from May 2009:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx

excerpt:

> As part of this re-architecture, we had to make the difficult decision **to reduce the scope to native C++ only for Intellisense.** We still index symbols coming from C++/CLI code and you can browse them with Class View etc...

The wording is a little opaque, but I think the meaning is: *there is no intellisense in C++/CLI projects in VS2010*.

Comment: +1 for the link but that is in WTF territory for those of us poor souls stuck with enormous C++/CLI source trees :(

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Agreed.  I am starting a new job next week and they want to write the low level hardware interfaces in CLI so that they can be easily called into from C#.  No intellisense makes me a sad panda...

Comment: @EdS.:  Visual Studio 2012 has IntelliSense for C++/CLI.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: That's very good to hear; I'll be using 2012 at the new job.  Thanks.