# How do you enable auto-complete functionality in Visual Studio C++ express edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, autocomplete

Please guide me, how do you enable autocomplete functionality in VS C++? By auto-complete, I mean, when I put a dot after control name, the editor should display a dropdown menu to select from.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2010 - if so, there is no IntelliSense for C++/CLI in VS 2010 (VS 2008 has it though), but IntelliSense for standard C++ projects should be working.

Answer (score 12):

Start writing, then just press CTRL+SPACE and there you go ...

Comment: it does not help me....first, it should be automatic, without clicking ctrl+space (even if you can force it with that command)...second I obviously tried it before looking solutions in internet and the problem is that in my case ctrl+space does not work either

Answer (score 5):

When you press ctrl + space, look in the Status bar below.. It will display a message saying IntelliSense is unavailable for C++ / CLI, if it doesn't support it.. The message will look like this -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's enabled by default. Probably you just tried on an expression that failed to autocomplete.

In case you deactivated it somehow... you can enable it in the Visual Studio settings. Just browse to the Editor settings, then to the subgroup C/C++ and activate it again... should read something like "List members automatically" or "Auto list members" (sorry, I have the german Visual Studio).

Upon typing something like std::cout. a dropwdownlist with possible completitions should pop up.

Comment: Its not like that, u mentioned!
Plz guide me!

Comment: Yes I have seen this solution on other sites as well, but am really sorry to say , its not working.
Anyway, appreciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

All the answers were missing Ctrl-J (which enables and disables autocomplete).

Answer (score 2):

- Goto => Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> C/C++ >> Advanced >>
  IntelliSense
- Change => Member List Commit Aggressive to True

Answer (score 1):

VS is kinda funny about C++ and IntelliSense.  There are times it won't notice that it's supposed to be popping up something.  This is due in no small part to the complexity of the language, and all the compiling (or at least parsing) that'd need to go on in order to make it better.

If it doesn't work for you at all, and it used to, and you've checked the VS options, [maybe this can help](http://www.windows-tech.info/4/d59787d312b9935a.php).

Comment: hmm....thanx dood!
But unable to get out of the problem!!!!
Need further suggestions!

Comment: @Asad: We'd need to know what you've tried, and whether it's working for you at all (even popping up tooltips when you mouse over variables and macros and such), and (if you know) what happened right before it stopped working in order to provide any help more specific than you've already gotten.

Comment: I am fresh user of VS C++ express edition and just started a project over it!
I have installed VS C++ express edition from microsoft website. Now while making the project i realized that there is no dropdown menu, after putting a dot. 
Since I am a new user and using VS C++ without this feature, is really problematic for me!
BTW choosing C++ for project is the requirment, otherwise I had intention to use C#.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Visual Assist X ? Sort of lights up the VS editor.

Comment: And time is money, using Visual Assist reduces significantly your coding time therefore not using visual Assist will cost you more money ;)

Comment: Is there any other solution. Because I am not buying the Visual Assist now. Any other option enabling make autocomplete , start working????
Need help

Comment: Not for supporting piracy, but I never paid a dime for the Visual Assist I use. Try playing around you will get it.

Comment: I have downloaded it !
But organisation has strict Piracy following poilicy!
Anyway thanx for suggestion!

Comment: Express Editions of Visual Studio do not support addins or tool extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I came across over the following post: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulperez/archive/2010/03/19/c-intellisense-options.aspx

The issue is that the "IntelliSense" option in c++ is disabled. 
This link explains about the IntelliSense database configuration and options.

After enabling the database you must close and reopen visual studio
for autocomplete use 'ctrl'+'space'

Answer (score 0):

'ctrl'+'space' will open C/C++ autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Include the class that you are using Within your text file, then intelliSense will know where to look when you type within your text file. This works for me.

So it’s important to check the Unreal API to see where the included class is so that you have the path to type on the include line. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's enabled by default. Probably you just tried on an expression that failed to autocomplete.

In case you deactivated it somehow... you can enable it in the Visual Studio settings.

[Step 1: Go to settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98hG5.png)

[Step 2: Search for complete and enable all the auto complete functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPA4j.png)

I believe that show help

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few recommendations from others, here's how I got mine to work again as of December 2023:

Go-to: Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C/C++ > IntelliSense

Enable everything and click "OK". Double-click your Ctrl key.

Hints and autocomplete should now be working.