# Intellisense on C++ (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Well, i've reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 (trial, from Microsoft site) but i'm noticing that Intellisense doesn't work. I've done this:

The thing of "No common language RunTime Support"
"Autolist Members" and "Parameter information"

But still i only get:

Intellisense: 'No additional available information'

It's a not precompiled header project, i don't have stdafx files...

How i make intellisense work? :(!

Comment: Does Intellisense work for a brand new Win32 project created with the New Project Wizard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No IntelliSense for c++/cli in visual studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681999/no-intellisense-for-c-cli-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No common language RunTime Support

This means you are not programming in C++. You're writing in C++/CLI instead. They are quite different languages; C++/CLI is more in character with C#. Visual Studio 2010 does not support Intellisense in C++/CLI projects. You need to use a native project, or live without Intellisense.

Comment: I read that as he has selected that option in the project properties which means he is compiling completely native (that is the default option).

Comment: @Sean: Most of the choices when you just go to "create a new visual C++ project" are not native projects. It's the default if you choose Win32 project, but I suspect the OP has not done that.

Comment: If you by 'most' you mean less than half, I agree ;)

Comment: i started a CLR console application
and i didn't get any intellisense neater ...
CLR is what you meant by native project right

Comment: @Eran: No, CLR is not native. CLR is the opposite of native.