# C++ environment with intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense

1. does any one know of a good development environment for C++ 
   that as working intellisense? VS seems not to have that ability on a very good scale

Plus I couldn't  figure out how to enable intellisense  in Visual Studios 2010.

1. How to enable  intellisense  in Visual Studios 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No IntelliSense for c++/cli in visual studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681999/no-intellisense-for-c-cli-in-visual-studio-2010) or [Intellisense for C++ in VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897755) or [Intellisense on C++ (Visual Studio 2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475122)

Comment: @Ben  i saw them ,
i was kinda looking for some old work  environment like the old borland but with intellisence so i could check my syntax , since i need to write something in C++ and iv'e never done that before.

Comment: As explained in those other questions, make sure you're not in C++/CLI (.NET mode).  Also, for syntax checking, the best thing is just to try to compile.  Intellisense is more for context-sensitive auto-completion of variable names.

Comment: o'k thanks 
i actually wrote a replay somewhere else stating that i am running a 
CLR console application .

btw -so just to make just there isn't like real intellisence ,like in C# , like if i write "s" in the application i wouldn't be offered the string class 
or references to other built in classes

Comment: If you're using C++/CLI, that's important information to include in your questions.  Anyway, you could try the new preview of Visual Studio v.Next that's included with the Win8 preview, or VC++ 2008, or you can get a third party plugin like Visual Assist X.  But VC++ 2010 does not include Intellisense for C++/CLI projects (already made clear in the other questions).

Comment: Also, if you're compiling against the .NET CLR, you really don't have any other options.  With standard C++, you could think about Eclipse (with the C++ plugin) or Code::Blocks, but C++/CLI is only supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio has excellent support for intellisense and it is enabled.

Comment: There are a large number of limitations on C++ Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010.  Simply saying there is no problem isn't helpful.

Comment: could you please explain to me how you enabled intellisense in VS2010
the msdn walkthrough got me to a dead end .

if you do this ill +up your nasty looking - ill even V your answer 
and you can get some yammi yammi reputation  
mmmmmm...... reputation ...aaaahhhhhhh(homer Simpson)
sorry i'm tired it's nearly 6 am here .

Comment: Actually, it is helpful as he thinks its not supported and it is. It is on by default, and it is reasonably good.

Comment: There are some issues that can cause it to stop however, you should google around and find out if this is what is affecting you. Here is one from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235519.aspx