# Visual C++ 2010 native Intellisense settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

So, I started programming in C++ moving from Java, Eclipse IDE. I use VS 2010 proffessional, I have it for free from DreamSpark.

However, I am very unhappy with its Intellisense, beeing far far worse than Eclipse (its C++ version) has. But almost everywhere on the internet I read that VS has great, superior Intellisense for native C++. So I want to ask, is there any way, some settings to change to make VS intellisense behave simmiliar to Eclipse? Or is there any other functionality in VS intellisense that compensate that?

To be exact, Eclipse intellisense does much better job guessing what object I want to create, suggests includes, generate keywords, generate few common for cycles etc...

I would not even as this question, but I found somuch possitive feedback on native C++ VS 2010 intellisense, so I have feeling I am doing something wrong... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing managed C++ (C++/CLI) there is a post explaining that intellisense is not currently implemented [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx)

As for alternatives you may like [visual assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/).

This question has also been answered before on Stackoverflow. Please see below for some alternative answers and suggestions:

[No IntelliSense for C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681999/no-intellisense-for-c-cli-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: The Visual Studio native C++ Intellisense feels like stone age compared to that, what Microsoft offers for C# and what you may be used from Eclipse.