# visual studio 2010 c++ intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense

Does somebody know how can I activate the intellisense for Visual Studio 2010 compiling in c++? When I write my code, functions inside a class never appear and this make the programming very difficult.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your project a pure native C++ project (No CLR).  Intellisense support for C++/CLI was removed in Visual Studio 2010, so only use C++/CLI where you absolutely must.

A couple of references below:

- [C++/CLI IntelliSense in Visual Studio vNext (VS Team Blog)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx)
- [No IntelliSense for c++/cli in visual studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2681999/94928)

Comment: When I open my project's configuration properties I don't have CLR support activate. So, why I can't see intellisense?