# Visual Studio 2013 C++ IntelliSense

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I'm using visual studio 2013 C++ and my IntelliSense is a bit weird, for example, when I type ***con*** for ***const*** the IntelliSense selector is in ***const*** but it is not highlighted yet so I have to move the arrow down then hit enter. How can I make it similar to C# IntelliSense, like it will automatically choose ***const*** when I hit spacebar or enter?

Comment: We all hope for better intellisense; for nowdays I recommand Resharper for C++.

Comment: They actually dropped IntelliSense support for C++ in Visual Studio 2010 (as [explained in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345389/copy-constructor-versus-clone)) for reasons like this, but then reintroduced it in Visual Studio 2012 and it's still not that great for C++. It's great if your using a .NET programming language though.

Comment: @ub3rst4r I'm pretty sure you meant to link to another answer

Comment: Oops... It was supposed to be this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681999/no-intellisense-for-c-cli-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I use VAX (Visual Assist) from wholetomato... this gives you intellisense like it should be. But it is commercial too.

Comment: I just tried what you said, typing "con" and pressing tab and it went straight to "const".

Answer (score 0):

You should press the TAB button instead. Whatever is in the selector is then gonna be typed in for you.

Like, in your example, when you typed **con** and the selector is in **const**, hit TAB and **const** will be typed in.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2017 go to

```
Tools/Options/Text Editor/C/C++/Advanced/IntelliSense
```

and change

`Member List Commit Aggressive` to `True`